# Solving equation involving shifts of the unknown function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Let's consider the following equation:
$$
a_2.f(t+2) + a_1.f(t+1) + a_0.f(t+0) = g(t)
$$
where $a_0,a_1,a_2$ are non zero reals and $g(t)$ is a known function.

Although it looks like an ordinary differential equation of order 2, the "changing" parts on the left part of this equation doesn't involve derivatives but rather a shift on the main variable $t$.

**Question(s):** what is the name of such an equation and what kind of methods do we have to find the unknown function $f(t)$ ?

Comment: Also called "difference equation", even if the differences are hard to see.

Comment: Fourier transform of shifted f is a phase shift in frequency domain on F. You could relate F to G, divide G by phase shifts to get F then transform back to time. You could probably express f in terms of g using contour integration, probably looks like poisson summation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursively defined sequence of the 2nd order. Assumming that $a_1\ne 0$, it becomes:
$$
f(t+2) = c f(t+1)+d f(t)+h(t).
$$
where $c=-a_1/a_2$ and $d=-a_0/a_2$, and also $h(t)=-g(t)/a_2$. Let $\lambda, \mu$ be the zeroes of the quadratic equation $x^2-cx-d=0$, then
$$
f(t+2) = (\lambda+\mu) f(t+1)+\lambda\mu f(t)+h(t),
$$
and hence
$$
f(t+2)-\lambda f(t+1) = \mu \big( f(t+1)-\lambda f(t)\big)+h(t).
$$
Set $F(t)=f(t+1)-\lambda f(t),$ then
$$
F(t+1) = \mu F(t)+h(t).
$$
If we know $F\restriction [0,1)$, then $F$ (and consequently $f$) is obtained, the same way we obtain the formula of the recursive sequence
$$
A_0=a, \quad A_{n+1}=\mu A_n+h_n, \quad n\in\mathbb N.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Important preliminary remark.**
It has to be noted that this kind of difference functional equation is linear with respect to $f$. Indeed, it can be rewritten as $Lf = g$, where $L = a_2S^2 + a_1S + a_0$, with $S(f(t)) := f(t+1)$ the shifting operator, is a linear operator and $g$ plays the role of an inhomogeneous source term. In consequence, the general solution to this equation is given by $f = f_h + f_p$, where $f_h \in \ker L$ is the solution to the associated homogeneous problem, i.e. $Lf_h = 0$, and $f_p$ is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation.

**How to find a particular solution ?**
The Fourier transform permits to handle the shifts as follows : $f(t+\tau) \to F(\omega)e^{i\omega\tau}$, where $F$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. In consequence, your equation becomes
$$
a_2F(\omega)e^{2i\omega} + a_1F(\omega)e^{i\omega} + a_0F(\omega) = G(\omega)
$$
hence
where $G$ is the Fourier transform of $g$, hence
$$
F(\omega) = \frac{G(\omega)}{a_2e^{2i\omega} + a_1e^{i\omega} + a_0},
$$
which you still need to invert in order to recover $f$. You may use the Laplace transform instead, the same procedure is valid.

Answer (score 1):

###### Equations Name

In Math.SE you can find equations like this under [functional-equations](/questions/tagged/functional-equations) or [recurrence-relations](/questions/tagged/recurrence-relations).
You can classify the equation in different ways, for example as a non-homogeneous linear advance [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) with constant coefficients (equivalent to a homogeneous linear delay functional equation or you could view it as an [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) of order $0$). It's also a [recurrence equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation) of order $0$, arithmetic difference equation ([Mathematica can solve such equations via `RSolve`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/RSolve.html))...

###### Solving this equation

You can solve them in different ways. Depending on the type of functional solution, the solution methods work and some don't. These are examples that work here:

###### $\mathcal{Z}$-transform

There is a quite useful transform like the Laplace transform called the [$\mathcal{Z}$-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) Like with the Laplace transform there are multiple possible definitions. It is often used because of its [special properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties) (especially its linearity and its time-delay or time-advance properties). Using the *bilateral* one:

\begin{align*}
a_{2} \cdot f\left( t + 2 \right) + a_{1} \cdot f\left( t + 1 \right) + a_{0} \cdot f\left( t + 0 \right) &= g\left( t \right) \tag{$\mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ \cdot \right]\left( s \right)$}\\
\mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ a_{2} \cdot f\left( t + 2 \right) + a_{1} \cdot f\left( t + 1 \right) + a_{0} \cdot f\left( t + 0 \right) \right]\left( s \right) &= \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right)\\
a_{2} \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t + 2 \right) \right]\left( s \right) + a_{1} \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t + 1 \right) \right]\left( s \right) + a_{0} \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t + 0 \right) \right]\left( s \right) &= \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right)\\
a_{2} \cdot s^{2} \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) + a_{2} \cdot s \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) + a_{0} \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) &= \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right)\\
\left( a_{2} \cdot s^{2} + a_{1} \cdot s + a_{0} \right) \cdot \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) &= \mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) \tag{$\div\left( a_{2} \cdot s^{2} + a_{1} \cdot s + a_{0} \right)$}\\
\mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ f\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right) &= \frac{\mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right)}{a_{2} \cdot s^{2} + a_{1} \cdot s + a_{0}} \tag{$\mathcal{Z}_{s}^{-1}\left[ \cdot \right]\left( t \right)$}\\
f\left( t \right) &= \mathcal{Z}_{s}^{-1}\left[ \frac{\mathcal{Z}_{t}\left[ g\left( t \right) \right]\left( s \right)}{a_{2} \cdot s^{2} + a_{1} \cdot s + a_{0}} \right]\left( t \right)\\
\end{align*}

###### Mathematica `RSolve`

[Mathematica can solve such equations via `RSolve`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/RSolve.html) and gives you a closed form solution. Using

```
RSolveValue[a[2] f[t + 2] + a[1] f[t + 1] + a[0] f[t] == g[t], f[t], t]
```

we get (raw output):

```
((-(a[1]/a[2])-Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]/a[2])^t*C[1])/2^t+((-(a[1]/a[2])+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]/a[2])^t*C[2])/2^t+((-(a[1]/a[2])-Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]/a[2])^t*Sum[-((2^(-1+K[1])*(-a[1]+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]])*g[K[1]])/((-((a[1]+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]])/a[2]))^K[1]*(a[0]*Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]))),{K[1],0,-1+t}]+(-(a[1]/a[2])+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]/a[2])^t*Sum[-((2^(-1+K[2])*(a[1]+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]])*g[K[2]])/(((-a[1]+Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]])/a[2])^K[2]*(a[0]*Sqrt[a[1]^2-4*a[0]*a[2]]))),{K[2],0,-1+t}])/2^t
```

or (the raw output in traditional form):

[image: traditional form]

It does look like Mathematica would use the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform here but that's not the case. But it could use it (Mathematica could use the *unilateral* definition).

###### Characteristic polynomial (solving for a homogeneous solution)

If our functional equation is linear, has only constant coefficients and contains only delays or advances then we could say that the non-homogeneous term is equal to zero, then substitute $f_{h}\left( t \right) := \text{constant} \cdot \lambda^{t}$ and solve for $\lambda$. The $f_{h}\left( t \right)$ we get is a homogeneous solution:

\begin{align*}
a_{2} \cdot f\left( t + 2 \right) + a_{1} \cdot f\left( t + 1 \right) + a_{0} \cdot f\left( t + 0 \right) &= g\left( t \right)\\
a_{2} \cdot f_{h}\left( t + 2 \right) + a_{1} \cdot f_{h}\left( t + 1 \right) + a_{0} \cdot f_{h}\left( t + 0 \right) &= 0 \tag{$f\left( t \right) := \lambda^{t}$}\\
a_{2} \cdot \lambda^{t + 2} + a_{1} \cdot \lambda^{t + 1} + a_{0} \cdot \lambda^{t} &= 0\\
a_{2} \cdot \lambda^{2} \cdot \lambda^{t} + a_{1} \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda^{t} + a_{0} \cdot \lambda^{t} &= 0 \tag{$\div\lambda^{t}$}\\
a_{2} \cdot \lambda^{2} + a_{1} \cdot \lambda + a_{0} &= 0 \tag{$abc$-formula}\\
\lambda_{1,\, 2} &= \frac{-a_{1} \pm \sqrt{a_{1}^{2} - 4 \cdot a_{2} \cdot a_{0}}}{2 \cdot a_{2}}\\
\end{align*}